# suppress gdb to print command number

Tags: gdb

In gdb, I would like to print just the command output and NOT the command number. For example, I get

```
$24 = {timeStamp = 15329666, id = 1, version = 1, checksum = 15329411}
```

instead I want it to output only

```
{timeStamp = 15329666, id = 1, version = 1, checksum = 15329411}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to print just the command output and NOT the command number.

The value `$24` is *not* the command number. It's the [value history](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Value-History.html) number of that particular output.

Use the [output](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Output.html) command if you don't want value history.